# Adding a Xamarin Component to Shared Code

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin project for both Android and iOS. I would like to use a Xamarin Component (from the store) in my shared code base. Currently, I have created a "Shared Project", but it seems like it is not possible to add the component to this project. Is this correctly understood? And if so, is there some kind of workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the component to all your platform specific projects and then you can use it on the shared project. If there are any discrepancies in the API's between the platforms you will have to resolve these with compiler flags or partial classes/methods.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/

> A Shared Project does not get compiled on its own, **it exists purely as
>   a grouping of source code files that can be included in other
>   projects.** When referenced by another project, the code is effectively
>   compiled as part of that project. Shared Projects cannot reference any
>   other project type (including other Shared Projects).

Comment: I don't understand how I can use the component in the shared project, since it cannot reference the other platform specific projects.

Comment: Think of shared project as a list of files to be compiled into the project referencing it. If you use file linking the files will pick up references from the project that is linking them. Shared project is very much like linked files but just grouped into a list so you won't have to update each project when a file is added or removed. See my updated answer for more info.

Comment: Ok. This is not exactly what I had in mind, but it's useful as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Components are platform specific.  To use platform specific code in a shared or PCL project you can use DI to pass a reference to a common interface into your shared code.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/